# Rails div for each block result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, block

I have a Rails 3 app where I'm using a block to loop through calls as below:

```
<div class="blah">
<% @call.each  do |call|  %>
<%= link_to call.incident_number, call%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I want to style the DIV to where it has rounded corners and is a certain size.  That's not a problem.  But what I've noticed is for each result of the block it continues in the same DIV.  I want each result to have it's own div so the results appear separated on the page.

How can I do this using DIV where each result of the block appears in its own DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `link_to` method in a div `content_tag`.

```
<% @call.each  do |call|  %>
  <%= content_tag :div, :class => "some_class" do %>
    <%= link_to call.incident_number, call %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was able to put a regular <div> instead of the loop to achieve the same effect.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its just a ruby code block that wraps anything in the do..end block in that specified tag. Glad I could help. If this answered your question please mark it as accepted to indicate that your issue has been resolved.